# Moving swap partition to External USB HD drive (not flash drive)

Tags: partitioning, lubuntu, swap

I have created a swap partition on an external USB HDD drive (not flash stick)
and set up /etc/fstab accordingly. The problem is that after reboot, system hangs and does not start. I am using Lubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the "USB legacy support" in the BIOS solved the issue.